# JS | From which interface does the addEventListener method comes from in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, addeventlistener

In modern browsers, the addEventListener property belongs to the [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) interface.

According to MDNs compatibility chart - it's being supported starting with IE9, however, I'm not able to access it from either IE9 or 10.

What interface does addEventListener belongs to in IE?

Comment: It may be that the question doesn't make sense when talking about older Internet Explorer versions; there may be nothing like what other browsers consider an "interface" to be, or if there's something it's something quite different.

Comment: Much older versions of IE implemented the DOM native objects such that they had nothing like a JavaScript prototype, for example.

Comment: According to this MSDN [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979674(v=vs.95).aspx), there's no interface at all, although generally speaking, these browsers do support all sorts of interfaces, including Element,HTMLElement and others. Element.prototype.addEventListener does exist, however, it's too low on the abstraction chain for my purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made some prototype chain sniffing on Edge/IE console:

IE11:
the window object,
You have the Window constructor, and Window.prototype.hasOwnProperty('addEventListener')
is true.

About html elements:
all of them gets it from constructor called `Node`

Node.prototype.hasOwnProperty('addEventListener')
is true.
(document.body instanceof Node) === tue

I believe it will be the same for IE9/10

On Edge its different, you do have the EventTarget object that in the prototype chain of html elements & window objects

I wonder if its spec incompatibility from IE side or its considered implementation details

Comment: Implementation detail - as far as the spec is concerned the prototype chain in JavaScript doesn't exist - from the other side JavaScript doesn't care about the DOM spec directly - and DOM objects (host objects in JS) can do whatever they want including not behaving like regular JS objects.

Comment: Doesn't the spec say something about if `document.body instanceof HTMLElement` should be true? (or any other element)